# Jenkins EC2 plugin starts and stops instance immediately when building the job

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am trying to create a new EC2 instance every time when there are no executors or number of jobs are in queues. All the jobs must run on slave node.

For the purpose, I came to know about **Amazon EC2 plugin**. I have done all the setup required and when I build the job it creates new instance but it also gets shutdown and terminated immediately.

It is also not showing up in ***Jenkins >> Node***

I don't know what is the exact cause. If it's the ***Idle termination time*** its set to 30.

```
Someone let me know the exact cause for it.
```

Comment: What does the jenkins log say about it? You should see entries like "Attempting to provision slave needed by excess workload of 1 unit" - what log entries are after that?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this symptom was resolved by allowing full network access between the master instance and the slave instance.